# Am I using Javascript call-backs appropriately (object-oriented style)?

Tags: javascript, callback, oop

I have the following code example to use an object that receives the action from the callback.  Doesn't seem like this is a good design pattern.  Or is it?

When `setTimeOut()` fires on the function after 1 second, it uses the `objInstance` global variable (DOM scope) to access the ClassExample object instance.  Can someone recommend a better way to utilize callbacks within an object oriented design?

The whole idea is so I can use the callback to update data within my object instance (increment a variable for example).

```
function ClassExample{
    this.initiate = function() {
        setTimeOut(objInstance.afterTimeOut,1000); //using the objects global handle
    }

    this.afterTimeOut = function() {
        alert("Received!");
    }

}

var objInstance = new ClassExample(); //instance
objInstance.initiate();
```

Comment: Wait, wat? That looks an aweful lot like over-OOPing it (as commonly found in e.g. Java). Why not `setTimeOut(function() { ... }, n)` (perhaps creating the function seperately just beforehand and giving it a descriptive name). Don't be afraid of that teensy glimpse of functional programming you would be using then.

Comment: I like the term "over-OOP" because it describes *lots* of Javascript I wrote back when I didn't understand how profoundly different it is from Java :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>No, you're not.  You'll want to do this:</strike>

```
this.initiate = function() {
    setTimeOut(objInstance.afterTimeOut,1000); //using the objects global handle
}
```

Now, if "afterTimeout" needs the proper object context, you could do this:

```
this.initiate = function() {
  var instance = this;
  setTimeout(function() { instance.afterTimeOut(); }, 1000);
}
```

OK well you changed the question considerably with that little edit :-)  If I were you, I'd just do this (like my original second example):

```
this.initiate = function() {
  var instance = this;
  setTimeout(function() { instance.afterTimeOut(); }, 1000);
}
```

Then you don't need any ugly global variables around at all.

*edit* — Stackoverflow user @Christoph comments that this isn't particularly pretty. One thing that might help would be to use a "bind" facility, as provided by newer browsers natively (as a method on the Function prototype) or by some libraries (Prototype or Functional for example).  What "bind" lets you do is create a little wrapper function like I've got above:

```
this.initiate = function() {
  setTimeout(this.afterTimeOut.bind(this), 1000);
}
```

That call to "bind" returns a function that is effectively the same sort of thing as the little wrapper I coded explicitly in the example.

Comment: Sorry about that edit, it was my typo.  Thank you for spotting.

Comment: +1 this is the way to do it, disregard my answer, but do consider my opening statement :)

Comment: Did you mean to say "instance.afterTimeOut()"?

Comment: @Pointy, does "self" refer to the instance now, or is it a copy?  I ask because I will be keeping track of data within this object.  Thanks!

Comment: Uhh ... well the "instance" variable will refer to whatever `this` was set to when "initiate" was called. If you call "objInstance.initiate()", then `this` will be that instance, and so that's what will be used to call "afterTimeOut" later. It's definitely not a copy of "objInstance".

Comment: Well, @Christoph, we haven't seen the rest of the code. If it were me, I'd probably make sure I had a "bind" function available and do it that way.

Answer (score 2):

```
function ClassExample{
    this.afterTimeOut = function() {
        alert("Received!");
    }; // Don't forget these

    setTimeOut(afterTimeOut, 1000); // Don't use () if you're passing the function as an argument
}

var objInstance = new ClassExample(); //instance
```

That way you don't need the `initiate()` method.

---

If you really want the `initiate()` method, I'd do it like this:

```
function ClassExample{
    var self = this;

    self.afterTimeOut = function() {
        alert("Received!");
    };

    self.initiate = function() {
        setTimeOut(self.afterTimeOut, 1000);
    };

}

var objInstance = new ClassExample(); //instance
objInstance.initiate();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd do it to allow timer reuse and minimize the number of closures:

```
function Timer(timeout, callback) {
    this.timeout = timeout;
    this.callback = callback;
}

Timer.prototype.run = function(thisArg /*, args... */) {
    var argArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    var timer = this;

    setTimeout(function() {
        timer.callback.apply(thisArg, argArray);
    }, timer.timeout);
};

var timer = new Timer(1000, alert);
timer.run(null, 'timer fired!');
```

---

And just for fun, a golfed version which is functionally equivalent, but replaces the object with a closure:

```
function delay(func, timeout) {
    return function() {
        var self = this, args = arguments;
        setTimeout(function() { func.apply(self, args); }, timeout);
    };
}

delay(alert, 1000).call(null, 'timer fired!');
```

Comment: Not sure I really see the benefit over the simpler self = this example.  Could you explain?  Thanks!

Comment: @Ryan: it works the same way (only `self` is called `timer`); however, you asked for 'good design', which means more than just making it work; some of my considerations: reusability (thus a general-purpose `Timer` class), readability (sane naming), efficency (pulling the methods out of the constructor means only a single function object has to be created instead of one per instance) and consistency (the signature of `run()` for `Timer` objects is the same as `call()` for `Function` objects)

Answer (score 0):

You are right it is not the optimal way of doing what you are aiming for. however i have to wonder why you need to break the callstack as part of the initiation, it seems very academic.

apart from that if i had to do that, i'd probably use a closure like so:

```
function ClassExample{
    this.initiate = function() {
        setTimeOut((function(self) { return function() { self.afterTimeout();}})(this),1000); //using the objects global handle
    }

    this.afterTimeOut = function() {
        alert("Received!");
    }

}

var objInstance = new ClassExample(); //instance
objInstance.initiate()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.initiate = function() {
    var instance = this;
    setTimeOut(function() {
        instance.afterTimeOut();
    }, 1000);
};
```

By saving `this` to a local variable, you can avoid using the global handle at all.  Also this prevent the `afterTimeout()` from losing it's `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Znarkus answer...

I really don't know in which environment his code is running but for me the first approach just do not works. I got: '**ReferenceError: afterTimeOut is not defined**'...

The second one, nevertheless, is really cool... I just changed setTimeOut for setTimeout (using lowercase 'o') and included parenthesis after the class name definition turning the first line of code into 'function ClassExample(){'; solved my problem.

My snippet of example code:

Oop with private behaviour, intern callback calling and etc.

```
function MyTry (name){
   // keep this object pointer... that's the trick!
   var self = this;

   // create private variable
   var d = new Date()toJSON().slice(0, 10);

   // create a private function
   function getName(){return name}

   // create public access method
   self.hello  = function(){alert('Hello '+getName()+'!\nToday is: '+d)}

   // note instance method hello passed as a callback function!
   self.initiate = function(){setTimeout(self.hello, 3000)}
}
```